# How do I find a cell in excel and print the value to python 3.6

Tags: excel, python-3.x

I am trying to get the value from a cell in excel and print the it into python (which seemed pretty simple) however i have 2 problems:

1. Python keeps issuing a warning (which i understand doesn't matter now but will in the future so i would like to fix it)
   [here is a picture of my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HrLn5.png)
2. My second problem is that when i print the cell it shows its formula not it's value [Here is a picture of the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YpEv2.png)

** [finally here is my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZEIDz.png) **

I would really appreciate it if someone could help

thank you

Comment: Please include the information relevant to your question *as text* in the question itself, rather than by linking to images. We can't copy and paste from images, and if they should become unavailable at some future time, your question would be impossible to understand.

Comment: thank you, will do @Blckknght

Answer (score 1):

There is an option in openpyxl during loading of workbook 'data_only', keep that as true and it wont return you the formula

```
import openpyxl
excel_document = openpyxl.load_workbook('scanza.xlsx', data_only=True)
sheet = excel_document['completetransaction']
print(sheet['F4'].value)
```

Comment: thank you that is really great. Do you know how i could get rid of my warning?

Comment: use excel_document['completetransaction'] instead of excel_document.get_sheet_by_name('completetransaction') in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Thank You, 
Thank you to everyone who has answered my question here is the finished code:

```
    import openpyxl
    excel_document = openpyxl.load_workbook('scanza.xlsx', 
    data_only=True)
    sheet = excel_document['completetransaction']
    print(sheet['F4'].value)
```